# Any attempt to connect to a server with ssh times out

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, firewall

after an attempt to get up a IKEv2 vpn server, I lost an ability to ssh to my server (the ssh just times out). I was able to console into the machine (with ubuntu) with hetzner console and reset all ufw rules.

My attempts to ssh to the server logs as this:

```
% ssh -vvv root@x.x.x.x
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/yurystepanov/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/yurystepanov/.ssh/config line 11: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname x.x.x.x is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/yurystepanov/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/yurystepanov/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
connect to address x.x.x.x port 22: Operation timed out
```

the hetzner tech person says that there is no other firewalls stand before my server
Is there any way to debug the connection process from the inside ssh machine or outside? Like mb there are other ways to block my ssh connection except the ubuntu firewall (ufw)
thank you guys!

Comment: A timeout usually (99% of all cases) indicates a firewall. What does `reset ufw rules` mean? We don't know. Check the status. Check the iptables for other rules that have been added outside of of ufw. Check if your local machine or network has outgoing connections restricted. Use traceroute to check where the timeout occurs.

Comment: try: `telnet x.x.x.x 22`  and see if it does connect, or just waits and timeouts. if it connects, the pb would be farther on the destination side (sshd setting that requires a dns lookup of incoming connections before allowing it? for exemple... look for the sshd logs in that case)

Comment: Since you were toying with a VPN on the server also check for correct routing.

Comment: you found the issue? i am having the same problem. it works from serverA to serverB, but not the other way around. Disabling fw on both side has no impact, suspecting some routing issue inside hetzner.